# Partial derivatives for box integral of a bivariate normal distribution

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution, partial-derivative, bivariate-distributions

I'm having quite a bit of trouble trying to understand how to to calculate partial derivatives of a specific function.

Suppose I have the standard bivariate normal density function:

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
f(x,y,\rho)&=&\phi_2\left(x,y \text{ }\bigg| \text{ }\text{mean}=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} ,\text{cov}=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & \rho \\ \rho & 1 \end{bmatrix} \right) \\
&=&\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp \left(-\frac{x^2-2\rho x y + y^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right)
\end{eqnarray}$$

where $\rho$ is the correlation term between $x$ and $y$.

I then create a function $F$ that represents the box integral of $f$ for $x\in\left[x_{\text{L}},x_{ \text{U}}\right]$ and  $y\in\left[y_{\text{L}},y_{ \text{U}}\right]$:

$$F(x_{\text{L}},x_{ \text{U}},y_{ \text{L} },y_{ \text{U} },\rho)=\int_{x_{ \text{L} }}^{x_{ \text{U} }}\int_{y_{ \text{L} }}^{y_{ \text{U} }}f(x,y,\rho)dydx$$

The derivatives I'm interested in finding are:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{ \text{L} }}, \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{ \text{U} }}, \frac{\partial F}{\partial y_{ \text{L} }}, \frac{\partial F}{\partial y_{ \text{U} }}, \frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho}$$

How on earth do I go about finding these derivatives?

I know that closed form integrals for the univariate, bivariate or multivariate normal density functions simply do not exist. But does that mean that I cannot calculate these partial derivatives either?

Thank you!

---

**Edit**

I've been able to make a lot of progress using the [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), aka differentiation under the integral sign. Shout out to [@eyeballfrog](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/395748/eyeballfrog) for the tip that I only need to use the one-dimension case.

I've been able to find values for $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{ \text{L} }}$, $ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{ \text{U} }} $ , $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y_{ \text{L} }}$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y_{ \text{U} }}$. However, I seem to have run into a snag for the partial derivative with respect to the correlation term, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho}$.

Here is how far I've gotten:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho} = \int_{x_{ \text{L} }}^{x_{ \text{U} }}\int_{y_{ \text{L} }}^{y_{ \text{U} }} \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho} f(x,y,\rho)dydx$$

The tricky thing is that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho} $ is SUPER messy. Here's what it looks like:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho} &=& \int_{x_{ \text{L} }}^{x_{ \text{U} }}\int_{y_{ \text{L} }}^{y_{ \text{U} }} \frac{\rho^3 - \rho^2 x y +\rho x^2 + \rho y^2 - \rho - xy}{2 \pi (\rho-1)(\rho + 1) (1 - \rho^2)^{3/2}} \cdot \text{exp} \left( -\frac{x^2}{2(1-\rho^2)} + \frac{\rho x y}{1-\rho^2} -\frac{y^2}{2(1-\rho^2)} \right)dydx
\end{eqnarray}$$

So it seems very unlikely that I'll get a nice "closed-form" solution for the double integral of $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho} $.

Does anyone see some sort of simplification that can be done here? For example, does $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho} $ contain the kernel of a modified bivariate normal distribution, or something like that? Because I honestly cannot see it here.

Thanks!!!

Comment: The [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) should give you all of them, but I doubt any will have an elementary form.

Comment: Since I posted this question, I've found my way to the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Higher_dimensions), but the section on "higher dimensions" seems to be specific to fluid mechanics and moving boundaries. So I'm having a really hard time adapting that process to this problem.

Comment: Yeah, ignore that. Consider that $\int_{x_-}^{x_+} \int_{y_-}^{y_+} f(x,y)dydx = \int_{x_-}^{x_+}\left[ \int_{y_-}^{y_+} f(x,y)dy\right]dx = \int_{y_-}^{y_+}\left[ \int_{x_-}^{x_+} f(x,y)dx\right]dy$ and use the one-dimensional version on the outer integrals as needed.

Comment: Oh, sweet! Ok, I'll give that a try, then. Thanks!

Comment: I arrived at the solution just a few days after this post was made, but I never got around to posting it here. This week I finally double and triple checked my results, compared my analytical solution against a few numeric cases and I finally feel like I can say this is the right answer. Thanks again [@eyeballfrog](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/395748/eyeballfrog) for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question, we will need to have access to the univariate normal density ($\phi_1$) and probability ($\Phi_1$) functions. For the sake of completeness, here are their definitions. Assuming a random variable $Z$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, we have:

$$\begin{equation}
  Z\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2) \Rightarrow
    \begin{cases}
      & \text{dens}(Z=z)=\phi_1\left(z|\text{mean}=\mu,\text{var}=\sigma^2\right) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2} \\
      & \text{prob}(Z<=z)=\Phi_1\left(z|\text{mean}=\mu,\text{var}=\sigma^2\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left[1 + \text{erf}\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right] \\
    \end{cases} 
\end{equation}$$

Now that we have access to $\phi_1$ and $\Phi_1$, we can write out the partial derivatives as follows:

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{ \text{L} }} = (-1) &\cdot& \left[\Phi_1\left(y_U|\text{mean}=\rho \cdot x_{ \text{L} }, \text{var} = 1-\rho^2 \right) - \Phi_1\left(y_{ \text{L} }|\text{mean}=\rho \cdot x_{ \text{L} }, \text{var} = 1-\rho^2 \right)\right] \\
&\cdot& \phi_1 \left(x_{ \text{L} }|\text{mean}=0,\text{var}=1 \right) 
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{ \text{U} }} = (+1) &\cdot& \left[\Phi_1\left(y_U|\text{mean}=\rho \cdot x_U, \text{var} = 1-\rho^2 \right) - \Phi_1\left(y_{ \text{L} }|\text{mean}=\rho \cdot x_U, \text{var} = 1-\rho^2 \right)\right] \\
&\cdot& \phi_1 \left(x_U|\text{mean}=0,\text{var}=1 \right) 
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y_{ \text{L} }} = (-1) &\cdot& \left[\Phi_1\left(x_U|\text{mean}=\rho \cdot y_{ \text{L} }, \text{var} = 1-\rho^2 \right) - \Phi_1\left(x_{ \text{L} }|\text{mean}=\rho \cdot y_{ \text{L} }, \text{var} = 1-\rho^2 \right)\right] \\
&\cdot& \phi_1 \left(y_{ \text{L} }|\text{mean}=0,\text{var}=1 \right) 
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y_{ \text{U} }} = (+1) &\cdot& \left[\Phi_1\left(x_U|\text{mean}=\rho \cdot y_U, \text{var} = 1-\rho^2 \right) - \Phi_1\left(x_{ \text{L} }|\text{mean}=\rho \cdot y_U, \text{var} = 1-\rho^2 \right)\right] \\
&\cdot& \phi_1 \left(y_U|\text{mean}=0,\text{var}=1 \right) 
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho} = f\left(x_\text{U},y_\text{U},\rho \right) - f\left(x_\text{U},y_\text{L},\rho \right) - f\left(x_\text{L},y_\text{U},\rho \right) + f\left(x_\text{L},y_\text{L},\rho \right)
\end{eqnarray}$$

In the last partial derivative $\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial \rho}\right)$, the $f$ function being referenced is, as defined at the top of the original question, the standard bivariate normal density function:

$$f(x,y,\rho)=\phi_2\left(x,y \text{ }\bigg| \text{ }\text{mean}=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} ,\text{cov}=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & \rho \\ \rho & 1 \end{bmatrix} \right)$$

The solution provided above relies heavily on the math found in [this other Stack Exchange post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/523584/215330) and, as pointed out in the comments above, the [Leibniz Integral Rule (a.k.a differentiation under the integral sign)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), and A LOT of Wolfram Alpha. Special thanks to [@eyeballfrog](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/395748/eyeballfrog) for pointing me in the right direction.

PS: Apologies for the weird formatting and alignment in some places. It's difficult to find a good way to visually represent these long equations.